# Android multi module with flavors to maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I've been trying to upload a project to a maven repository unsuccessfully. Here is my project structure :

```
_root
  |_ lib1 (aar)
  |_ lib2 (aar) 
  |_ javalib (jar)
```

- lib1 depends on lib2
- lib2 depends on javalib
- lib1 and lib2 have two flavors (intg and prod)

Problem is when I launch uploadArchives task I have no pom.xml created.
It seems to be due to my flavors (when I remove flavors it works fine), and I can't figure out how to fix this problem.
I really need to work with flavors ... any help is welcome ;)

here are my build.gradle files :

root :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

ext.versionName = "$System.properties.version"

configure(subprojects) {

    apply plugin: 'maven'

    group = 'com.test.build'
    version = project.versionName

    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/content/repositories/test/") {
                    authentication(userName: "admin", password: "admin123")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

lib1 :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    publishNonDefault true

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName project.versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        prod{}
        intg{}
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    intgCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'intgRelease')
    prodCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'prodRelease')
}
```

lib2 :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    publishNonDefault true

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName project.versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        prod{}
        intg{}
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':javalib')
}
```

javalib :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the answer to my issue :
it is NOT possible, but it might be possible to do it one day :
see documentation about that : 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication

I went through this problem with this solution :

```
// default publication is production which will be published without env name
    publishNonDefault true
    defaultPublishConfig "productionRelease"
    if (android.productFlavors.size() > 0) {
        android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            // Publish a main artifact, otherwise the maven pom is not generated
            if (android.publishNonDefault && variant.name == android.defaultPublishConfig) {
                def bundleTask = tasks["bundle${name.capitalize()}"]
                artifacts {
                    archives(bundleTask.archivePath) {
                        classifier null
                        builtBy bundleTask
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not satisfied with it but it will do the job for now ...

Answer (score 0):

I spend a lot time to discover why my Android project din't upload my modules to maven. The problem is because I didn't set the `defaultPublishConfig` inside the `android {}` brackets in the file `build.gradle`. The snippet below is how I solved my problem. You need set what flavor you wanna publish to Maven (access **build variants** tab in the Android Studio to see all your flavors name):

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        defaultPublishConfig "myFlavorDebug"
    }
}
```